# Django - create profile for all existing users

Tags: python, django, backend, django-users, django-3.0

i'm using Django 3 , this is my userprofile model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.utils.text import slugify 
from django.db.models import signals

# Create your models here.

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=1000,blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='userimg/',default='userimg/avatar.png')

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.user

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.user)
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.get(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)

def delete_user(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):
    try:
        instance.user
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    else:
        instance.user.delete()

signals.post_delete.connect(delete_user, sender=Profile)
```

the problem is that the function create_user_profile create profiles only for the new users but doesn't create for the old users , so how can i fix that ?

Comment: You can make the edit profile form and make the user add it manually for the old user..i think that the only solution

Comment: i'm serching for an automatic way i don't want to do that manually

Comment: @Ninou: well using signals is a bit of an antipattern in the first place: https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/

Answer (score 2):

You can make a [*data migration*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations). You create one with:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations --empty app_name
```

where you replace `app_name` with the name of the app that stores the `Profile` model. In the migration, you can then make `Profile` models:

```
from django.db import migrations
from django.conf import settings

def make_profiles(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    Profile = apps.get_model('app_name', 'Profile')
    profiles = [Profile(user=user) for user in User.objects.filter(profile=None)]
    Profile.objects.bulk_create(profiles)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app_name', '1234_some_migration'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(make_profiles),
    ]
```

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: @Ninou: no, as said, that is a migration file. Once you run the `makemigrations`, it will add the `Profile`s to the `User`s that are missing a profile. How would this "fit" in a model?

Comment: i did what you told me but when i did py manage.py migrate it showed me this error "LookupError: No installed app with label 'django.contrib.auth'." i don't know why cuz i have 'django.contrib.auth' in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: @Ninou: what if you make use of the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting instead?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: @Ninou: what if you use `User = apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)` instead?